# HTML video doesn't fit its place

Tags: html, css, html5-video

In my HTML code, I have put a video like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <video id="video1" controls preload>
        <source src="media/interview.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<script>
    // jQuery method
    $('video').mediaelementplayer();
</script>  
</body>
```

And the CSS part is:

```
#video1
{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But, when I play it, it doesn't fit its place, and I have a result like this:

[image: Application]

Comment: show your relevant code, this is not enough

Comment: I add some informations. But what it miss ?

Comment: Video will take the max `width` and when it reaches the max `width` , `height` will stop getting bigger unless you put a fixed size for `height`

Comment: I set a fixed size for heigt (ex : 100px) -> The result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what it is that you are trying to do, but I assume you want to move it...? You can use `margin-left:20px;` or `margin-right:20px;` to move the video around. If you want to resize it, you need to give us the dimensions of the video. If you want to test this, in chrome hit ctrl + c and highlight the video and hover above the video and at the styles page in the css live editor, scroll down and find the size and change the values.

Comment: I just want the video, in the correct size of the object video before it plays.

Here, the video is outside the place it must to be....